# loading a css file from 'assets' directory in a NUXT layout

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

in a nuxt layout (default.vue) I want to load an image and a css file from assets folder
the image loaded successfully, but the css file not, why?

/layouts/default.vue

```
<template>
<img src="~assets/photo.jpg" />
 <!-- converted to /_nuxt/assets/photo.jpg and loaded successfully -->
</template>

<script>
export default{
 head:{
  link: [  { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '~assets/style.css' }]
}
}
</sript>
```

when I view the source code:

```
<link href="~assets/style.css" />
```

and it fails to be loaded

also navigating to http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/assets/style.css faild, but http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/assets/photo.jpg successed

***note:***

I don't want to put style.css in 'static' folder as I want to load it via webpack css-loader to add caching hashes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image src is automatically compiled by Vue, you can see more  at [relative path import](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports); From the docs:

> all asset URLs such as `<img src="...">`, `background: url(...)` and CSS
>   `@import` are resolved as module dependencies.

For a custom path besides cases listed above, you need to explicitly require the path for it to be compiled as a path to static assets:

```
export default{
  head:{
    link: [{ rel: 'stylesheet', href: require('~assets/style.css') }]
  }
}
```